# Spigot Algorithm derivation logic

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, algorithms

The Wikipedia article on Spigot algorithm includes the following derivation and I don't understand how the head and tail divide the sum in third equation listed below. Can someone please elaborate on how to get to the third step?

This example illustrates the working of a spigot algorithm by calculating the binary digits of the natural logarithm of 2 (sequence A068426 in the OEIS) using the identity

${\displaystyle \ln(2)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{k2^{k}}}\,}$

To start calculating binary digits from, as an example, the 8th place we multiply this identity by 27 (since 7 = 8 − 1):

${\displaystyle 2^{7}\ln(2)=2^{7}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{k2^{k}}}\,}$

We then divide the infinite sum into a "head", in which the exponents of 2 are greater than or equal to zero, and a "tail", in which the exponents of 2 are negative:

${\displaystyle 2^{7}\ln(2)=\sum _{k=1}^{7}{\frac {2^{7-k}}{k}}+\sum _{k=8}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{k2^{k-7}}}\,}$

Answer (score 1):

I see now, the exponents switch from 7-k to k-7. I missed that detail when I posted. I hope this helps someone else!